# How to expose Kafka and Zookeeper ports in cloud foundry

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, cloud-foundry

Is there a way to expose `kafka` and `zookeeper` port in `CF`? I pushed spotify/kafka docker image to cloud foundry. Both `localhost:2181` and `localhost:9092` are working properly but how can I make these ports visible for other applications? I was expecting for example `kafka.run.pivotal.io:2181` and `kafka.run.pivotal.io:9092` would be accessible but that is not the case. I really appreciate your input. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bind kafka/zookeeper service instance with the application in which you want to use it:

```
cf bind-service APP_NAME SERVICE_INSTANCE
```

After this operation url of the created service instance will be in VCAP_SERVICES environment variable of the application. Check with:

```
cf env APP_NAME
```

All you need to do now is to get the url of the service instance by parsing VCAP_SERVICES on the application side. This step depends on the language/framework you're using.